# Disable default shipping option on cart refresh Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

We are using the following snippet to disable the default shipping method/option on the cart and checkout in Woocommerce:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', '__return_false', 99);
```

This works well, but it fails when the cart page is refreshed or if the user leaves the cart page and returns. We are using the new block cart.